# Why is CORS request failing even after setting "esponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");" in servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, servlets, cors

I have a question relating to a Tomcat-hosted servlet running on a cloud server.

I have a web application consisting of (at this time):

• 13 HTML files in a folder

• a separate CSS file in a subfolder named “css”

• a separate Javascript (JS) file located in a subfolder named “js” that contains a number of library functions including a CORS request function

• a Java servlet packaged in a WAR file

• a web.xml file

• a MySQL database

I’ve tested this application on my laptop using NetBeans (with WildFly as the web server), MySQL and the FireFox browser and everything worked perfectly.

I then set up Tomcat on a cloud server, replicated the database, and installed the WAR and web.xml file and set the context path using the Tomcat control panel.

I've consulted the forums here and other locations and checked the cloud hosting provider's forums as well.  I THINK I'm doing everything I need to enable CORS requests, but there must be some subtle mistake I'm making somewhere or something I've overlooked and I'm currently at an impasse.

### Javascript Code

My Javascript CORS function (in the JS library file) looks like the following:

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
//  xhr.withCredentials = true;     // do I even need to do this – and -
    xhr.withCredentials = "true";   // which is correct – string or logical?
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
        // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  // is this correct?
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
        // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  // is this correct?
    } else {
        // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}
```

Also, elsewhere in the same file, I define the constants I need for various invocations of the function:

```
var PARAM_CMD = "&cmd=";   
…
var CMD_GET_MAP = 310;
…
var PARAM_TBL = "&tbl=";
…
var PARAMS_GET_HASHMAP = PARAM_CMD + CMD_GET_MAP + PARAM_TBL;
…
var HASHMAP_STATES = 1130;
…
var urlname = "http://TestSite.com/TestServer/TestServer?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
```

The following is a typical invocation of this code:

```
function populateUSStatesBox() {
  var fullURL = urlname + PARAMS_GET_HASHMAP + HASHMAP_STATES;
  var xmlhttp = createCORSRequest("GET", fullURL);
  // handle changes to the request state
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if ((xmlhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) && (xmlhttp.status === HTTP_RESP_OK)) {
      var StatesMap = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      setupComboBox ("cboUSStates", StatesMap);
    }
  }
  // send the http GET request with the command parameters sent in the header
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

### Java Code

On the server side, near the beginning of the servlet’s doGet code, I set the response header values according to postings I’ve seen on various forums. I only actually send [mostly] GET requests and a few POSTs (but not, at this time, any PUTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs or OPTIONs).  I know the  “*” value for  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is dangerous for production, but I’ve just opened it up for testing.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
   .
   .
   .
// response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 
request.getHeader("Origin"));   // is this correct?
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
   "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
response.addHeader("Pragma", "public");
.
.
.
}
.
.
.
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException {
   doGet(request, response);
}
```

The Java file containing the servlet is called TestServer.java; the package name is TestServer.

### Configuration Information

The Tomcat directory structure (Linux/Centos) is:

```
var
   lib 
      tomcat 
         webapps
            TestServer
               TestServer.war
               WEB-INF
                  web.xml 
               META-INF
                  context.xml
```

context.xml contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Context path="/TestServer"/>
```

The web.xml file has the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> TestServer. TestServer </servlet-class>
    <display-name>Test System</display-name>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>loginName</param-name>
        <param-value>#####</param-value>   Note: I’ve obscured the LoginName
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>connectionPWD</param-name>
        <param-value>#####</param-value>  Note: I’ve obscured the connectionPWD
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dbURL</param-name>
        <!--param-value>localhost/</param-value-->
        <!--param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/</param-value-->
        <param-value>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dbName</param-name>
        <param-value>#####</param-value>  Note: I’ve obscured the dbName
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debugging</param-name>
        <param-value>on</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServer</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ TestServer</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

### Results

When I try to load one of these web pages on my local system, I get the following error reported in my Firefox console (and same happens in Chrome and Opera as well):

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://testsite.com/TestServer/TestServer?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&cmd=310&tbl=1130. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

If the code executed correctly, one of the SELECT boxes in my web browser would show a list of states.  But, of course, I get nothing populated because of the CORS error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This code looks ok, BUT what access level do you have on cloud? @SteveParis

Comment: I'm the administrator and have full access.

Comment: I realized that I had the wrong context.xml file loaded; the correct code is: 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context path="/TestServer"/>

Sorry about that!  New to asking a question on this forum and I tried to do careful proofing before I posted!

Comment: So are you saying that when you use the correct file contents it now works? Or, just that you put the wrong contents in your question, and have now edited it to correct the inaccurate information in the question, but that you still have the problem?

Comment: No, it's still not working.

I meant to say that I had just copied the wrong contents of Context.xml into THIS post but I updated that listing above. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue before, where essentially from the javascript code you're not allowed to create a request with ContentType being set to application/json to back end servlet.

The Content-Types acceptable from javascript/website to backend for request:

1. application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2. multipart/form-data
3. text/plain

So in short change your Javascript CORS Content-Type to be one of those 3.

Here's more information about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers#Directives

> Note that certain headers are always allowed: Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type (but only with a MIME
>   type of its parsed value (ignoring parameters) of either
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or
>   text/plain). These are called the simple headers, and you don't need
>   to specify them explicitly.

Comment: Thank-you for the information - I made that change.  However, there is still something weird going on. I get an error: 

 "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: The cloud server provisioned by the cloud-hosting company came with NGINX and Apache; I just installed vanilla Tomcat.  

I believe there may be a port conflict or path error.  I don't know NGINX at all and I'm not as familiar with Apache+Tomcat as I am with WildFly.  How would I check for this?